# mysqli get the id from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

category tbl

```
cat_id   name    type 
1        cloths   boy
2        cloth    girs
3        bags      boy
4        bags      girls
```

---

sub cat. tbl

```
subcat_id   cat_id    subcat_name
1            (?)        jeans
```

Now in subcategory table I want to get cat_id.

In subcategory form user can select category->cloth and cat_type->boys...
Then I want to add that category id in subcategory table.

Comment: I don't know on which interface your appliation is running, i assume it's a webapplication? Perhaps you can make a hidden field where you place the category id. When submitting the form read the hidden field so you can insert it in the subcat table.

Comment: yes it is web application. But now I'm learner. 
Please explain me how can I do that..

Comment: Look into [joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

On your form add a hidden field to keep the categoryid

```
<form name="myform" action="<youraction>" method="POST">
 <input type="text" size="25" name="CatName" value="Cloths">
 <input type="text" size="25" name="CatType" value="Boy">
 <input type="hidden" name="CatId" value="1">
</form>
```

On posting your form, read the value from the hidden field with the name CatId and insert it in the table sub cat.

**Option 2:**

Before inserting into subcat table, make a query that get's the cat id.

```
SELECT Cat_Id FROM Cat_tbl WHERE name = 'cloths' AND type = 'boy'
```

Hope it's a bit clear to you.